# How to hide the background image of div already hidden by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

This one is a bit confusing to explain. On my page http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10mm/abduction.html 
i have a show 'more' and 'less' option. When clicked, a drop down appears with text and a background image. However a small section (the top) of the background image of the dropdown div, wont hide. Does anyone know why this may be?

the html for this is below, followed by the css:

```
<div id="MORE">

    <button id="more">More</button>
    <button id="less">Less</button>

<div id="instructions">
    <p style="display: none"> The Mayor of Scaredy Cat Town has been abducted. Lawlessness has broken out across London and the city needs your help    to find him. Follow the links on this site to scour the city in search of The Mayor. A reward, courtesy of The Mayor and his staff, is  available for anyone able to find him. <br /> The Reward... <br /> An exclusive night of entertainment at the Mayors up-market bar, hosted by his   head waiter,Henri. </p>
</div>

    <script>
        $("button#more").click(function () {
        $("p").show("slow");
        });

      $("button#less").click(function () {
      $("p").hide("slow");
    });    
    </script>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#MORE {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}

#more, #less {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: From your link it appears you have got this working. You should accept an answer if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove style="display: none" from p and add it to the div with id instructions and then try this :

$("button#more").click(function () {

```
    $("div#instructions").show("slow");

    });

  $("button#less").click(function () {

  $("div#instructions").hide("slow");

});
```

Comment: I have tried this, as well as altering .instructions for #instructions. Niether work. Im struggling to find what is stopping the top from being hidden!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are hiding the `p` tag and the background is on its container `intructions.` Hide that instead.

```
$("#instructions").show("slow");
```